# How to say "I prefer x over y"?

Tags: translation, grammar, comparison

For example:

> I prefer eating fried rice over fried chicken.

How to say that in chinese?

How about this?

```
我较喜欢吃炒饭比炸鸡
我炒饭比炸鸡较喜欢吃
```

Comment: `我喜欢炒饭胜过炸鸡.` You can also say plainly, `比起炸鸡, 我更喜欢炒饭`.

Comment: Actually in English we don't say this anyway. We would say "I prefer eating fried rice **to** fried chicken." or "I prefer eating fried rice **over** fried chicken."

Comment: I agree with hippie, 'over' is what I would use here. As for the topic, what have you tried?

Comment: alright, I corrected the word in order not to confuse other people in future.

Comment: Related: [A more direct translation for “I \[verb\] \[x\] more than \[y\]”](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/19454/a-more-direct-translation-for-i-verb-x-more-than-y)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I prefer X to Y can be translated as:

- 我喜欢X**甚于**Y
- **比起**Y**来**，我**更加**喜欢X
- 我喜欢X**的程度要超过**Y
- 我喜欢Y，**更加**喜欢X

So,

> I prefer eating fried rice over eating fried chicken.
>  我喜欢炒饭**胜过**炸鸡

Comment: Just got a thought. Can I say like this? 我炒饭比炸较喜欢吃

Comment: @suud People can understand you, it's just a little weird. You kinda of sound like Master Yoda.

Comment: I just corrected the word "than" to "over" in my question post, could you do the same in your answer? Btw there is a missing character (鸡) at above comment, it should be 我炒饭比炸鸡较喜欢吃.

Answer (score 2):

the answer should be like this：
比起Y，我更喜欢X

Comment: Can you give an example using my question case?

Answer (score 2):

the answer can be this:相比y，我更喜欢x

Comment: Can you give an example using my question case?

Answer (score 2):

Chinese people don't say this. You can't force a language into any structure that happens to be common in English. 我喜歡X ("I like X") is good enough. Or 我更喜歡X ("I prefer X").