# A more direct translation for "I [verb] [x] more than [y]"

Tags: translation, sentence-structure

I don't know how to directly translate a sentence like this:

> I [verb] [x] more than [y]

I would usually translate it like this:

> [x] 比 [y] 更 [some adjective that captures the same meaning as the verb]

For example, "I love you more than my phone" would become "你比我的手机更亲爱".

Is there a more direct translation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a very direct translation.

If "more than" means higher degree/level of the [verb], then `I [verb] [x] more than [y]` can be translated to `我 [verb] [x] 甚于 [verb] [y]`.

```
I [verb] [x] more than [y]. 我 [verb] [x] 甚于 [verb] [y].
I love you more than my phone. 我 爱 你 甚于 爱 我的手机.
```

甚于 means "surpass, exceed", indicating the degree/level of the [verb].

If "more than" means a larger number/amount, then 甚于 should be replaced with 多于.

```
I play basketball more than football. 我 玩(打) 篮球 多于 玩(踢) 足球.
```

You may notice that the verb appeared twice in the Chinese translation. The second verb is there to avoid ambiguity. There is no case(grammar) in Chinese. A pronoun is always in the same form whether it's accusative case or nominative case. If you say

```
我爱你甚于他
```

then I don't know whether you mean

```
I love you more than he does. 我比他更爱你
```

or

```
I love you more than him. 我爱你甚于爱他.
```

If you are sure no ambiguity will be introduced, then you can leave out the second verb. As in

```
我爱你甚于我的手机.
```

There is only one reasonable interpretation, that is

```
I love you more than my phone.
```

No one will interpret it as

```
I love you more than my phone does. 我比我的手机更爱你.
```

In this case, the second verb can, but doesn't have to, be left out. It's always OK to specify the second verb.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful answer.

I notice that, in both cases, you specify the verb a second time. Can you ever leave the second verb out if they are the same?

Comment: @Frank Tan. You can leave out the second verb if you are sure no ambiguity will be introduced. I added several lines talking about this.

Comment: 甚于 sounds a little bit too formal. Maybe 胜过? Well, anyway, the structure sounds good, and there should be plenty of words that can be applied here.