# Mandarin: different ways of asking if someone prefers A to B

Tags: grammar, mandarin

[This question is similar](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/6390/how-to-say-i-prefer-x-over-y) but doesn't address this question of comparing different ways to express the notion of preferring A to B.

Are all these ways valid grammar for asking if someone prefers A to B? (In this case A is Chinese food while B is American food.)

Expression #2 seems like it might be wrong.

1. 妳喜歡中國菜多過美國才嗎?
2. 中國菜比美國菜妳喜歡多嗎？
3. 妳覺得中國菜比美國菜好吃嗎?

Comment: 多过 already implies comparison, therefore no 比 (as in 1st example),中国菜她喜欢吃多过吃美国菜吗？

Comment: Probably the most colloquial way would be: [你觉得]A好，还是B好呢？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentence 3 is correct in grammar.

> 妳覺得中國菜比美國菜好吃嗎?

I would probably put:

> 1. 中国菜和美国菜，你更喜欢哪一种？
> 2. 你喜欢吃中国菜还是美国菜？
> 3. 中国菜和美国菜，你觉得哪个更好吃？

Comment: For #1 could you also say 中国菜比美国菜，你更喜欢哪一种？

Comment: 中国菜比美国菜 is an incomplete phrase. The complete version could be 中国菜比美国菜好吃 or 中国菜比美国菜更好吃. These twos could be used as complete sentences as well. Usually, ...比...+ a descriptive word could be considered as the fixed structure, like, 你比他好。 他比你强。他比我强多了。他比我有魅力。她比我漂亮。 ....

Answer (score 2):

There're hundreds of way to say 'prefers A to B' in Mandarin, consider we really love making 'hint'. That's not the scope of this question.

Besides,

> 中國菜比美國菜妳喜歡多嗎？

is not correct in grammar.

Ways to say 'Do you prefer A to B?" in genal. **It does not strictly follow 'A to B'**. Pretty much like a daily conversation:

```
    1. 你喜欢A, 还是喜欢B?
    2. 喜欢A吗？还是B?
    3. A好还是B好？
    4. 你选A还是B?
    5. A和B, 你倾向哪个？
```